# is it safety to compress LINUX ISO file and approach suggestion

Tags: linux, rhel, tar, zip, iso

We are working to upgrade our rhel servers ( `rhel 7.1` ) to `rhel 7.8` by *rhel 7.8 ISO* file

Since we have **296** rhel servers version `rhel 7.1` we plan to do the upgrade as the following

We build Linux centralize server to keep on this server the ISO file - `rhel-7.8.ISO`

On the other servers - `rhel 7.1` ,  we copy the ISO file by `SCP` or `rsync` the ISO file from the  centralize server , and upgrade the `rhel` to `7.8` by yum install

Since the `ISO` file is huge file around `6 GIGA`

We want to know what is the best approach to compress / shrink the `ISO` file

I will appreciate to get any good suggestion

Comment: You would not be able to compress the ISO file system very much if most of the files on the filesystem already are compressed.  I'm assuming that the 6 GB are mostly package files. If I'm not mistaken, these are usually compressed already.

Comment: may I ask with which approach better to transfer the ISO file for example - SCP or RSYNC or other (  we should to the copy in parallel on all machines )

Comment: `rsync` with otf-compression should be "good enough". Although i doubt it makes any larger difference. ubuntu server image is 914M as ISO and 890M as .gz

Comment: You have now asked three separate questions: 1) Is it safe to compress the ISO file? 2) How may the file be compressed? and 3) How may it be transferred?  I suggest that you clarify which of these questions is the main one, or whether there is some other question regarding the approach that you are considering.

Comment: based on your first note , I think the 3 question is now more important to me

Comment: Regarding the upgrade scenario, have you considered building a single, local repository server using the packages from the ISO? `yum` can then connect to it with the appropriate configuration. This seems a lot easier to manage, compared to moving the ISO image around the entire network.

Comment: yes this is a great idea , please post this , I think is the best solution